# Как убрать повторы параметров командной строки?

Tags: cmd, c++

Всем привет.

Есть простая программа по выводу параметров командной строки. А как вывести параметры командной строки без повторов?

**Обновление 1**

Всем большое спасибо за ответы. Заранее прошу прощения за то, что напишу далее. Я учусь, а когда учишься, следует задавать вопросы, которые пусть и покажутся знающим неслыханной ахинеей. Обучаюсь по книгам "ООП в C++" Р.Лафоре, и Керниган, Ричи, "Язык С" + видеоуроки от "Специалиста" по языку С (в перспективе С++). Пытаюсь работать в Visual Studio 2013.

Что ещё посоветуете из литературы, видеоуроков, практики?

***Вопрос 1***

> [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) Например, составьте set из них.

Итог - вот это чудовище. Эта вопиющая безграмотная ересь закономерно не работает (частично списано с примера из книги Лафоре set.cpp):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { set<string> Mnozh; printf("Before upgrade:\n"); for (int i = 1; i<argc; i++) printf("Arg number: %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    // Инициализация множества массивом
    set<string, less<string> > nameSet(argv[i]);
    // итератор
    set<string, less<string> >::iterator iter;
// размер множества cout << "\Word's count in dictionary: " << Mnozh.size() << endl; iter = nameSet.begin(); while (iter != nameSet.end()) cout << *iter++ << '\n'; system("pause"); return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
```

Как синтаксически верно инициализировать множество массивом?

**Обновление 2**

***Вопрос 2***

Пробовал вывод через списки. Не очень вариант, потому что `unique()` убирает только те повторы, что стоят рядом. Моё аляповатое писание:

```
include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std; int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { printf("Before upgrade:\n"); for (int i = 1; i<argc; i++) printf("Arg number: %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]); // need stdio.h //cout << "Word " << i << " = " << argv[i] << endl;
list<char>Param;
printf("\nCreate list and push back array...\n");
for (int j = 0; j < argc; j++)
Param.push_back(argv[j]);
Param.unique();
    system("pause");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

В этом коде при компиляции ошибка:

```
error C2664 : "void std::list<char,std::allocator<char>>::push_back(const _Ty &)" : невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "char " в "char &&" 1> with 1>[ 1> _Ty = char 1>] 1> Причина: невозможно преобразовать "char " в "char" 1> Не существует контекста, в котором такое преобразование возможно.
```

Поясните для тех, кто в замечательном танке, что это значит. На пальцах.

**Обновление 3**

***Вопрос 3***

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), что имелось в виду под "разбором argv[]"?

Есть несколько вопросов по вашему коду:

А. Почему `int j;`, а не `for (int j = 1...`?

Б. Поясните: `for (j = 1; j < i && strcmp(argv[j], argv[i]); j++)` означает: инициируем цикл с условием: до тех пор, пока `j` не будет меньше `i` и при этом выполняется лексеграфическая проверка значений `argv[j]` и `argv[i]` (если они равны, вернётся 0);
`if (i == j) puts(avgv[i]);` означает: если значение `i` и `j` совпадают, выводим очищенные от повторов значения параметров командной строки?

**Обновление 4**

***Вопрос 4***

> [[@0xFFh](/users/10774/0xffh)](/users/10774/0xffh) действительно, используйте std::set<T>. Если с STL особо не знакомы, банально с помощью двумерного массива удаляйте повторы.

Окей. Получилось... нечто забористое. И неработающее. Стыдно показывать, но есть вопрос: как проверить уникальность слова в параметрах командной строки, если использовать двумерный массив?

Comment: Приведите пример кода, который не работает.

Comment: Например, составьте `set` из них.

Comment: @Ivanovich, действительно, используйте `std::set<T>`. 
Если с STL особо не знакомы, банально с помощью двумерного массива удаляйте повторы.

Comment: @0xFFh, зачем удалять с помощью двумерного массива?

--

Предполагая, что аргументов не очень много, напечатать их без повторов (и гарантировано по их порядку в argv[]) можно так:

     for (int i = 1; argv[i]; i++) {
       int j;
       for (j = 1; j < i && strcmp(argv[j], argv[i]); j++);
       if (i == j)
         puts(avgv[i]);
     }

--

@Ivanovich, Вас интересует такой вариант утилиты `echo`, или Вы хотели спросить о разборе `argv[]`?

(тогда о нем и спрашивайте)

Если речь о разборе, то все не так просто. Для правильного разбора нужно иметь описание допустимых опций и их аргументов.

Comment: @avp, почему бы и нет? Далеко не самый худший способ.

Comment: Как добавлять Очень Большие Комментарии?

Как добавлять красивый код а-ля @avp ?

Comment: @lvanovich, 1) вопросы на этом ресурсе следует задавать вопросами, а не комментариями; 2) вопросы в стиле "я не понимаю, как работают базовые конструкции языка" - не для этого форума.

Comment: @Ivanovich, здесь количество комментариев под каждым вопросом/ответом ограничено 4 шт. для участника. А максимальный размер комментария - 600 символов.

Поэтому что-то существенное обсудить в комментах не получается. Либо задавайте новый вопрос, либо дополняйте этот (а в комменте, который потом можно удалить, пишите - "обновил вопрос в N-ый раз" (сами сообразите, как выделять обновление)).

Для форматирования кода в комменте отделяйте его пустой строкой

    и вствляйте 4 пробела
    перед каждой строкой, а для
       отступов в коде добавляйте еще пробелы
       в начале строк.

(не влез...)

Comment: Ответы на Ваши вопросы мне.

3) Про аргументы и их разбор читайте [тут](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments)

a) Такой код работает и в Си и в C++, потом, просто лень набирать `-std=gnu99` для gcc, а кресты я не люблю.

б) Да. Смысл -- сравниваем все до `argv[i]` с ним, если дошли до конца, то повтора не было -- надо печатать.

Обратите внимание, оба цикла от 1, а не от 0, поскольку по соглашениям argv[0] это не аргумент, а имя программы.

Comment: @Ivanovich: Вот вам пример с `std::set`: http://ideone.com/fKcZU7 (поскольку там аргументы передавать нельзя, я их эмулирую вручную).

Comment: @Ivanovich, так что-нибудь работающее все-таки получилось?

Наверное, в общем случае для удаления дубликатов из массива самым быстрым способом будет такой -- отсортировать массив, а затем за один проход удалить дубликаты (перемещая уникальные элементы влево (к началу)).

Попробуйте для тренировки.